# HTML OData Query Builder

Tags: html, odata

I developed an OData web services which exposes my entity framework model, now I need to develop a Query Builder like this,

http://odata.intel.com/QueryBuilder

[image]

Are there any HTML or JS plugin I could use, I am open to JQuery or Angularjs, bootstrap or any other plugin available instead of recreating wheel.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: As @Tiberiu pointed out below you want to use this: https://odatasamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/115752

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. https://odataquerybuilder.codeplex.com/

```js
var url = 'https://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc';
var builder = new Xrm.oData.QueryBuilder(url)
   .setEntity('Orders')
   .setColumns('OrderID,CustomerID,ShipCountry')
   .setExpand('Order_Details')
   .setFilters(new Xrm.oData.FilterInfo({
    filterType: Xrm.oData.FilterTypes.And,
    filterExpressions: [
     "ShipCountry eq 'Sweden'",
     'OrderID lt 10800'
    ],
    filters: [
     new Xrm.oData.FilterInfo({
      filterType: Xrm.oData.FilterTypes.Or,
      filterExpressions: [
       "CustomerID eq 'BERGS'",
       'OrderID gt 10700'
      ],
      filters: [],
     }),
    ]
   }))
   .setOrders([
    new Xrm.oData.OrderColumn({
     column: 'CustomerID',
     order: Xrm.oData.OrderTypes.Asc
    }),
    new Xrm.oData.OrderColumn({
     column: 'OrderID',
     order: Xrm.oData.OrderTypes.Desc
    })
   ])
   .setSkip(10)
   .setTop(5);

var queryString = builder.getQueryFiltersPart();
console.log(queryString);
```

```html
<script src="http://yourjavascript.com/58162111474/odata-querybuilder-0-1-min.js"></script>
```

Result: $select=OrderID,CustomerID,ShipCountry&$expand=Order_Details&$filter=(ShipCountry eq 'Sweden') and (OrderID lt 10800) and ((CustomerID eq 'BERGS') or (OrderID gt 10700))&$orderby=CustomerID,OrderID desc&$skip=10&$top=5

2. https:// odatasamples.codeplex .com/releases/view/115752

This one generates html ui based on service metadata. You can customize it according to your needs by modifying it.
After download and before run, modify "datajs-1.1.1.js", line 2593:

- from

  ```
  xhr.open(request.method || "GET", url, true, request.user, request.password;
  ```
- to

  xhr.open(request.method || "GET", "https:// cors-anywhere.herokuapp .com/" + url, true, request.user, request.password);

** bug fix (http:// stackoverflow .com/questions/30318371/northwind-odata-service-not-working)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ejrkl.jpg)

Comment: Thanks, please explain how this will work as I think it's for CRM only ?